# Special character from database are displayed incorrect

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little php program which send emails to customers.

The email containes text which is written as html code and also contains data from my MySQL database.

I have tried to change the encoding for the email as UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

Depending on the encoding either the html text or the database data is displayed wrong when a word includes special characters.
How do I need to change setting so my emails are displayed correct.

Comment: What sort of wrong are you talking about here? How are you rendering the email? What encoding shows up in the raw source of the received message?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very limited. I guess your using the code below in your html.

```
<meta charset="...">
```

I also guess that your using `mysqli` to retrieve the data from the database and you not using

```
mysqli_set_charset()
```

Here is the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) for the function above.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I did not describe my problem clear enough.

I wanted to send emails through a php file. This email would contain text which is included in the file but also data from a database.

In my php file header I am using

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">`

In the email header `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";`

The emails then contains strange symbols for all special letters for parts which are taken from the database.

I have found the following solution which helped me to solve the problem. Just after the database connection it is required to enter the following few lines.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```